# how to install android ADT plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am getting this constant error: Unable to connect to repository http://dl-ssl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml through eclipse whenever I try to install the Android ADT plugin(through Adding Repository: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ in Help->New Softwares).
My one possible suspect is that in entering proxy.(in Windows->Preferences->General->Network Connections). I have turned Active Provider to Manual and further I have entered host name, port name along with authentication id to HTTP and HTTPS schemes leaving behind SOCKS.
But still I am not able to connect to repository, further I have tried different versions of the link by making it https:// or by removing the last forward slash.
Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The correct url = "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/", you don't need content.xml in the url.

Comment: Try the troubleshooting section where you can install the ADT manually http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html